# How to use Entity Framework 7 in class library?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to make the work with data in a class library with asp.net core 1. I created `MyDbContext` in a class library:

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> Profiles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            // maybe need to add foreign key
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Profile)
                .WithOne(u => u.User)
                .HasForeignKey<UserProfile>(p => p.UserId);
    }
}
```

My `project.json` in class library:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "DatabaseCore Class Library",
  "authors": [ "alex-pc" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.10.0",
        "System.Data.Entity": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Data": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "dependencies": {

  }
}
```

And updated `startup.cs` in web application:

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {

            builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
        }
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"]);
            });
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        //services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        //{
        //    options.AddPolicy("API", policy =>
        //    {
        //        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        //        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        //    });
        //});
        services.AddAuthentication();
        services.AddCaching();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            options.Audience = "resource_server_1";
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:4871/";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
        });

        // Add a new middleware issuing tokens.
        app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
        {
            options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;
            options.AuthorizationEndpointPath = PathString.Empty;
            options.TokenEndpointPath = "/connect/token";

            options.Provider = new AuthorizationProvider();
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

My `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": ""
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Data": {
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=DESKTOP-R3AP4AT\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
  }
}
```

Now I want to make the migration to create the database. Using commands in cmd

```
 dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-final
 dnx ef migrations add MyFirstMigration
 dnx ef database update
```

First, all performed well, the database was created, but does not create a table, database is empty. If i added this code:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                @"Data Source=DESKTOP-R3AP4AT\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
```

**error - instance crashes**,
Result:
[image: cmd result]

Comment: What error? That's an important detail to leave out.

Comment: instance crashes in cmd red error=(

Comment: That's not specific enough. What exactly does the error say?

Comment: I added screen in my post, i'm deleted method  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)  and error missing, migration added database, but doesn't tables =(, db is empty

Comment: Generally you wouldn't get an InvalidOperationException alone without anything else. I suspect this is a bug and that you might consider opening an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Looks like your database is not reachable or the system cannot access it. 
Is it configured for windows auth? What user are you using to connect to that database? Does it have permissions to create tables?

Comment: Thanks for answer ). I'm using local database and user have default permission. Database is created, but the tables are not created...IF using MVC 5, all works fine...I'm renewed my full startup.cs...

Comment: I think the instance failure is occurring because the connection string is incorrect:

    @"Data Source=DESKTOP-R3AP4AT\\SQLEXPRESS;...

Should actually be

    @"Data Source=DESKTOP-R3AP4AT\SQLEXPRESS;...

Or 

    "Data Source=DESKTOP-R3AP4AT\\SQLEXPRESS;...

I.e. don't use both a verbatim string (prefixed with @) and double backslash. 

I am adding this as a comment because I am not sure this answers your main question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed

```
"commands": {
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
},
```

in the `project.json` of your library.

When I moved my EF model into a library I followed the instructions from here: http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/moving-entity-framework-7-models-to-external-project

Meanwhile I moved from RC1 to RC2 nightly and my `project.json` of the library looks like this.

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "DhrData Class Library",
    "authors": [ "noox" ],
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",

    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Commands": "1.0.0-rc2-20270",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-20270"
    },

    "commands": {
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Reflection": ""
            }
        },
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {           }
        }
    }
}
```

Lately I did not use migration because I had too much changes while playing around with EF Core. Instead I created a console application which recreates the database and fills it with some data. This is already for RC2 (and you probably do not need the custom Appsettings).

```
using System;
using DhrData.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DhrConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        private IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        public AppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }  // object for custom configuration

        private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            serviceCollection 
                //.AddEntityFramework()   // RC1
                .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()  // RC2
                .AddDbContext<DhrDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

            serviceCollection
                .AddScoped(p => new DhrDbContext(p.GetService<DbContextOptions<DhrDbContext>>()));

            serviceCollection.Configure<AppSettings>(s => Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var applicationEnvironment = PlatformServices.Default.Application;

            new Program(applicationEnvironment);
        }

        public Program(IApplicationEnvironment env)
        {
            //var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
            //loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);

            // Set up configuration sources.
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile("config.{env.EnvironmentName.ToLower()}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

            // custom application settings
            AppSettings = new AppSettings();
            Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(AppSettings);

            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
            serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

            using (var dbContext = serviceProvider.GetService<DhrDbContext>())
            {
                RecreateDb(dbContext);
            }
        }

        private void RecreateDb(DhrDbContext dbContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EnsureDeleted ...");
            dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            Console.WriteLine("EnsureDeleted ... Done!");
            Console.WriteLine("EnsureCreated ...");
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
            Console.WriteLine("EnsureCreated ... Done!");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

If not necessary I would not recommend to update to RC2 as long as it is not final. It's a pain. But there are quite some bugs in EF RC1 which have already been fixed in RC2 nightly builds.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to leave the connection string in the `AddDbContext<TContext>()` call in the application's Startup.cs and to use  `MigrationsAssembly()` to tell EF where the migrations will be located (which should probably be alongside the DbContext). E.g.:

```
services.AddEntityFramework().AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .MigrationsAssembly(assemblyName));
```